# #Error Generation error: Unable to find plugin in the plugin search path: Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium

Tags: selenium, nunit, specflow

I'm using specflow v1.9.0 Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit v1.3.1 and when I try to build the project, I'm seeing the below error

```
`#error Generation error: Unable to find plugin in the plugin search path: Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit. Please check http://go.specflow.org/doc-plugins for details.`
```

And in the App.config I got the below code

```
 <specFlow>
   <unitTestProvider name="SeleniumNUnit" />
   <plugins>
      <add name="Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit"  path="..\packages\Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.1.3.1\tools" /> 
   </plugins>
   <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.Bindings" />
   </stepAssemblies>
 </specFlow>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar error but with a different plugin and the steps outlined in [Unable to find plugin in the plugin search path: SpecRun when saving / generating feature files](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Troubleshooting-Visual-Studio-Integration#unable-to-find-plugin-in-the-plugin-search-path-specrun-when-saving--generating-feature-files) resolved it for me:

*1. Make sure the NuGet folders are properly restored.

 2. Close Visual Studio.

 3. Delete the `bin\Debug` folder from your project(s).

 4. Reopen your solution in Visual Studio.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the given path the file "Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.SpecFlowPlugin.dll" exists.

When are your *.feature.cs files generated? When you save the file or at build?
If it is at saving, regenerate the code behind file.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for replying. I do have "Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.SpecFlowPlugin.dll" in the tools folder \packages\Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.1.3.1\tools. i genearted `.feature` file manually using specflow extensions for VS2015. When i build the project i see above

Answer (score 0):

The solution above didnt work for me. The issue was only resolved when I've tried the following:

1. Go to VS->Tools->Options
2. Go to SpecFlow
3. Go to Test Execution
4. Change Test Runner Tool to something else than SpecRun and Auto (NUnit, MS...)
5. Build the project. This time it should work.
6. Change the Test Runner Tool back to SpecRun
7. Enjoy :)

[Test Runner Tool option in Tools->Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utHcZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Still if you are facing same issue uninstall the plugin Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit and install it again